# Moment Generating Function of Subgaussian Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, machine-learning, moment-generating-functions

I have been working through Vershynin's "High-Dimensional Probability" recently, and have been having some trouble with the chapter on subgaussian random variables (2.5). In Proposition 2.5.2, one of the equivalent definitions of a sugaussian random variable is the following condition on the moment-generating function (MGF):
$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda^2 X^2}\right] \leq e^{K^2_3 \lambda^2},$$
where $|\lambda| \leq \frac{1}{K_3}$, and $K_3$ is a constant. Later, after introducing the subgaussian norm, this condition is restated the following way:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda X}\right] \leq e^{C \lambda^2 \|X\|_{\psi_2}^2}.$$
when $X$ is a zero-mean random variable and for some (new) constant $C > 0$.

Now, I don't quite understand how we get from one to the other. I would guess it is not too hard, since it was just given as restating the proposition, but I think I haven't quite understood the transition from the constants in the proposition to the use of the norm. I thought perhaps each constant was just equal to some scalar multiple of the norm, but I can't explain to myself why we need zero-mean in this case, or why the squares disappear.

Comment: Suppose $X$ satisfies such a bound. Can you show $X$ has zero expectation?

Comment: Also, this is not stated correctly. $\lambda \leq 1/K_3$ is not needed.

Comment: @AndrewZhang After looking a bit more through the book and doing some reflecting, the zero-mean condition should just be because of Hoeffding's lemma, correct? As to your second comment, why does $\lambda$ not need to be bounded?

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right. The condition on $\lambda$ is needed, I did not see that it is the MGF of $X^2$. As for the zero mean condition, I think it is actually presented awkwardly in the book. The point of the zero mean condition is that $E e^{\lambda X}\leq e^{\lambda^2 \sigma^2/2}$ for some $\sigma >0$ implies $EX=0$. This should be a straightforward exercise to show. Put another way, suppose $$E e^{\lambda X}\leq e^{\lambda^2\sigma^2/2 +\lambda\mu}$$ for some $\mu \in \mathbb R$ and all $\lambda\in \mathbb R$. Show $E X = \mu$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Ok yeah, that makes sense. I am still confused about the connection to the restated condition though...

Comment: The moments of a random variable are intimately related to the tails. So bounds on the moment generating function (in particular, the mere existence of the MGF (c.f. Billingsley's probability and measure section on method of moments) are more or less the same as bounds on tail probabilities. When you consider the absolute moments of $X$, evidently the moments of $X^2$ grow faster. The point is that $X$  is sub-gaussian (i.e. has gaussian like tail probability decay) if and only if the moments of $X^2$ decay sufficiently fast.